# Comparator for set defined in the class of the set elements

Tags: c++, stl, set, comparator

I have a class, and the pointers to the objects of this class need to be placed in a `std::set`. I want to define the comparator *inside* the class. I have seen a few solutions where either a separate class is defined (I guess it is called a functor), or a structure is defined which overloads the `operator()`. I want to avoid this boilerplate code, and want to define a comparator as a member of the class itself, something along the lines of Java's `compareTo()` method.

Let us say, my class is something like:

```
class Item {
private:
    int id;
    float score;
.....
public:
// Rest of the methods and setters/getters
}
```

I want to define the comparator in a way that pointer to object having a higher score are placed first in the set. If the score is equal for the two, then the one with the lower id is placed first. I guess the code will be something like the following, but since I did not understand this part very well, please correct me (I would like this to be placed inside the class itself):

```
bool operator()(const Item* a, const Item* b) {
    if (a->score != b->score) return a->score > b->score;
    return a->id < b->id;
}
```

The usage would be as follows:

```
std::set<Item*> sortedItems;
Item* item = new Item();
sortedItems.insert(item);
```

I am not sure if the comparator needs to be specified at all in the `std::set` template if defined within the class, and if so, how? Also, how do I add this comparator in the class itself? I am new to STL, and fairly new to C++ as well. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to define `operator<` for Item.

Comment: @ahenderson I see. And the arguments to this will be pointers to Item or Item itself? Also, if `operator<` is defined, will I not need to specify any comparator to the `std::set`? I am using the `set` of pointers to `Item`, and not the actual objects themselves. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: sorry i didn't notice you had a set of pointers

Comment: It's quite trivial to write a templated `ptrOrder<T>` which orders two `T*` using `std::less<T>`, which in turn defaults to `operator<(T, T)`. This might be beneficial if your `Item` already has a working `operator<` and `std::less<Item>`

Comment: @MSalters I see. Thanks! But since the `Item` class has neither those, simply writing a comparator will also suffice.

Comment: Using pointers and naked `new` is very un-C++, because handling lifetime is error prone. Modern C++ style is to use smart pointers or some kind of handles. And you can overload the `operator<` for those, because they are class types.

Comment: @JanHudec: No, not really. You can't go out and overload `operator<` for `std::shared_ptr`. In which namespace would you do that? Remember, `std::set` has to find it and you can't add overloads to `namespace std`.

Comment: @MSalters: In the namespace of T, of course. 3.4.2/2 says that associated namespaces of class template instantiation includes associated namespaces of it's type template parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this solution is inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/999400/942596).

```
#include <set>

class Item {
private:
    int id;
    float score;
public:
    struct compare {
        bool operator()(const Item* a, const Item* b) {
             if (a->score != b->score) return a->score > b->score;
             return a->id < b->id;
        }
    };
};
```

Because set allows you to define your own comparison method you can use it as follows.

```
std::set<Item*, Item::compare> sortedItems;
```

This should allow your class Item to work with set

Comment: Yep. This works fine! Thank you! I was hoping for something without having to declare a structure, but I guess this is the best way. Still, a structure as a member of the class is much cleaner than a separate structure or class. Thank you once again!

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I searched for! But what happens if you change the score of one of the already inserted members? I guess you have to erase and re-insert it, because the set itself can't check if one of its members changed, right?

Comment: @v01pe If your planning to make a change to whats in the set I would remove it first make the change then re-insert it.

Answer (score 2):

The `set<T>` implementation wants to call `a < b` where `a` and `b` are objects of type `T`. As long as that call is valid, the set doesn't care; it can be a non-static member function that takes **one** argument, a static member function that takes two arguments, or a free function that takes two argument:

```
class Item {
public:
    bool operator<(const Item& rhs) {
        return score == rhs.score ? id < rhs.id : score < rhs.score;
    }
static bool operator<(const Iterm& lhs, const Item& rhs) {
    return lhs.score == rhs.score ? lhs.id < rhs.id : lhs.score < rhs.score;
}
};

bool operator<(const Item& lhs, const Item& rhs) {
    return lhs.score == rhs.score ? lhs.id < rhs.id : lhs.score < rhs.score;
}
```

Any one of those three is okay. Of course, if you write two or more of them, you'll get ambiguities.

Comment: I don't think std::set will call any of the methods when comparing pointers.

Comment: Thanks! Please note that the set will be of type `set<Item*>`, whereas overriding the `operator<` is defined for `Item`. It does not seem to work in this case (the set is sorted according to the order of insertion, which is, I presume, because the pointers are compared).

Comment: @ahenderson - right. I didn't notice that the question asked about a set of pointers. Nevertheless, my answer is correct <g> because it talks about a `set<T>`.

Comment: @Paresh - for pointers you can't write an overloaded `operator<`, because the language already defines one for you. So do as ahenderson suggested: write a separate compare function and pass it to sort.